# Column Mismatch Error in Gridview - Using Hyperlink Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sharepoint-2010, attachment

I used a `gridview` to select the columns from a List dynamically. The lists also have an attachment field. So I have the attachment file url in a variable called attach.

Ex: `attach = "http: //sok:1234/Lists/CapabilityTableSales/attachments/1/Dashboard Solutions.pptx"`

I used the following Code !!

```
private void PopulateGrid()
        {

           try
            {
                // List is Hard Coded here . we can also use current Context instead//
                string SiteListURL = "http://sok:1234/Lists/Case%20Studies/";


                using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(SiteListURL))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.Query = "";

                        if (txt_Search.Text != String.Empty)
                        {
                            txt_Search.Text = "Key1";
                            query.Query = @"<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Key%20words' /><Value Type='Text'>" + txt_Search.Text + "</Value></Contains></Where>";
                        }

                        query.ViewFields = String.Concat(
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />",
                            "<FieldRef Name='Key%20words' />",
                            "<FieldRef Name='Project%20Brief' />",
                            "<FieldRef Name='Execution%20Highlights' />");
                        query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

                        SPList list = web.Lists["Case Studies"];
                        SPListItemCollection col = list.GetItems(query);
                        dt = web.Lists["Case Studies"].GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Attachment", typeof(HyperLink)));
                        foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            drow["Attachment"] = getURL(drow["Title"].ToString());
                            //Where the function getURL will return the attachment URL!! (Working Fine)
                        }

                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
           }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw ex;
            }

        }
```

How ever getting a column mismatch error for the line `drow["Attachment"] = getURL(drow["Title"].ToString());`

My requirement is to open the file (PPTs) on click of that URL.

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a data type mismatch. I guess your `getResult` is returning something other than type : `HyperLink` which is what your data row expects.

Comment: I am not sure about that, my result is "http: //sok:1234/Lists/CapabilityTableSales/attachments/1/Dashboard Solutions.pptx". I want a hyperlink to this URL...

Comment: Looks like you may have to use SPMenu field. Refer here for more details - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx

Comment: Get rid of that by changing the hyperlink field to a string field and used anchor template HREF property as the attachment URL.